# An attempt to create a balance between debit and credit

Tags: sql

Well, I'll go directly to the case that is presented to me when trying to make a book with Extract and MUST HAVE in continuous BALANCE.

I was really hanging in my consultation, and I can not find any solution for desired.

Thanked would in some small contribution to some of you.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
        ACCDATE     ACCOUNT DEBIT    CREDIT    BALANCE
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    1500.00 -1500.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    60.00   -1560.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    400.00  -1960.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    100.00  -2060.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    300.00  -2360.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    250.00  -2910.00
```

OR:

```
        ACCDATE     ACCOUNT DEBIT    CREDIT   BALANCE
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    1500.00 0       1500.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    60.00   1440.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    400.00  1040.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    40      1000.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    300     0       1300.00
2013-01-01 00:00:00 11200    0.00    250.00  1550.00
```

I really do not require account type filter it by this time, but specific.

The idea is that with my Query still does not give me that result.

They can buy creating a provisional or temporary table with the same shown below:

```
INSERT INTO Accounting (AccDate,DebitCredit,Account,Amount) VALUES ('20110101','D',11200,1500)
INSERT INTO Accounting (AccDate,DebitCredit,Account,Amount) VALUES ('20110101','C',11200,60)
INSERT INTO Accounting (AccDate,DebitCredit,Account,Amount) VALUES ('20110102','D',11200,400)
INSERT INTO Accounting (AccDate,DebitCredit,Account,Amount) VALUES ('20110102','C',11200,100)
INSERT INTO Accounting (AccDate,DebitCredit,Account,Amount) VALUES ('20110102','C',11200,300)
INSERT INTO Accounting (AccDate,DebitCredit,Account,Amount) VALUES ('20110102','C',11200,250)

WITH CTE_FIRST AS
(
    SELECT ACCDATE,
        ACCOUNT,
        CASE WHEN DEBITCREDIT='D' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS DEBIT,
        CASE WHEN DEBITCREDIT='C' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS CREDIT,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ACCOUNT,ACCDATE) RN
    FROM ACCOUNTING
    WHERE ACCDATE >='20130101'

)
,CTE_SECOND AS( 
    SELECT *,
          ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 DEBIT FROM CTE_FIRST B WHERE B.ACCOUNT=A.ACCOUNT AND B.RN<A.RN ORDER BY RN DESC),0) COL1,
          ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 CREDIT FROM CTE_FIRST B WHERE B.ACCOUNT=A.ACCOUNT AND B.RN<A.RN ORDER BY RN DESC),0) COL2
    FROM CTE_FIRST A
)

SELECT ACCDATE,ACCOUNT,DEBIT,CREDIT,
    CASE WHEN DEBIT=0 THEN 0-(CREDIT+COL2) ELSE DEBIT+COL1 END BALANCE
FROM CTE_SECOND
```

Something happens in the validation of sum or not it's taking so linear consulting ....

All of this inquiry, I tried to help me with material that I got on the web. But it gives me the total response.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I got this solution, but it becomes very slow the process.

Is there a way to optimize it?

Very slow for real, and it does not work for high queries.

> DECLARE @T TABLE( FECHA DATETIME, COMENTARIO NVARCHAR (300), CUENTA
>   VARCHAR(15), DEBE NUMERIC(15,2), HABER NUMERIC(15,2) )
>
> INSERT INTO @T SELECT FECHA, COMENTARIO, CUENTA, DEBE, HABER FROM
>   DIARIOAPUNTES;
>
> /* INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('001-0001','20130102',100,0); INSERT INTO @T
>   VALUES ('001-0001','20130102',0,200); INSERT INTO @T VALUES
>   ('001-0001','20130102',100,0); INSERT INTO @T VALUES
>   ('001-0001','20130103',100,0); INSERT INTO @T VALUES
>   ('001-0001','20130105',0,100); INSERT INTO @T VALUES
>   ('001-0002','20130105',100,0); INSERT INTO @T VALUES
>   ('001-0002','20130106',500,0);
>   */
>   --DEBIT - CREDIT + BALANCE
>
> WITH T_ROW AS (
>       SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (T1_1.FECHA) ASC)) AS CONTADOR, FECHA, T1_1.CUENTA, T1_1.COMENTARIO, T1_1.DEBE, T1_1.HABER
>       FROM @T T1_1 )
>
> SELECT T1.CONTADOR, T1.CUENTA, T1.COMENTARIO AS DESCRIPCION,
>   Convert(CHAR(10), T1.FECHA, 103) AS FECHA, T1.DEBE, T1.HABER,
>   ROUND(T1.DEBE-T1.HABER + COALESCE(T2.SALDO,0),2) AS SALDO FROM T_ROW
>   T1
>         CROSS APPLY(
>               SELECT ROUND(SUM(DEBE)-SUM(HABER),2) AS SALDO
>               FROM T_ROW T2
>               WHERE T2.CONTADOR < T1.CONTADOR AND T1.CUENTA = T2.CUENTA
>         ) AS T2
>         --WHERE T1.FECHA BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20131231'
>         ORDER BY T1.CUENTA, T1.FECHA
>   --WHERE T1.ACCOUNTNO = '001-0001'